# Changing formulas on the fly with VBA RegEx

Tags: regex, excel, vba

i'm trying to change formulas in excel, i need to change the row number of the formulas.

I'm trying do use replace regex to do this. I use an loop to iterate through the rows of the excel and need to change the formula for the row that is iterating at the time. Here is an exemple of the code:

```
    For i = 2 To rows_aux
            DoEvents

            Formula_string= "=IFS(N19='Z001';'xxxxxx';N19='Z007';'xxxxxx';0=0;'xxxxxxx')"
            Formula_string_new = regEx.Replace(Formula_string, "$1" & i)
            wb.Cells(i, 33) = ""
            wb.Cells(i, 33).Formula = Formula_string_new
      .
      .
      .
   Next i
```

I need to replace rows references but not the ones in quotes or double quotes. Example:
If i = 2 i want the new string to be this:

```
"=IFS(N2='Z001';'xxxxxx';N2='Z007';'xxxxxx';0=0;'xxxxxxx')"
```

I'm trying to use this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)
```

But its changing everything in quotes too. Like this:
If i = 2:

```
"=IFS(N2='Z2';'xxxxxx';N2='Z2';'xxxxxx';0=0;'xxxxxxx')"
```

If anyone can help me i will be very grateful!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note - normally you don't need to loop when writing formulas. If you have relative references, you can write the formula to the entire range and Excel will update the reference row by row.

Comment: There are a lot of formulas that i get from a worksheet that is always changing(a way to make the macro configurable), all the info i have is the formula in that sheet, and i can't put any formula through the code and i have to check in every row, i want to make in a way that is fast because there are a lot of rules.

Comment: I also think that no need to check. Excel doesn't make mistakes if you correctly write the formula (only once).

Comment: Where does that `Formula_string` come from?   If it's a template string you could include distinct placeholders in it rather than actual cell addresses.  That way you would avoid replacing other bits of the string too.

Comment: In this code i put as example, but Formula_string  is getting a formula from a cell in a workbook of rules that is constantly changing. I can't change the original formula or create a new one in the code, i have to use what is in the cell, and because i have just one formula in a sheet, i have to adjust the formula for the line in iterating. I do a lot other stuff in each line, that is just one thing i have to do. @chrisneilsen can you elaborate or write an example? i don't think i got it.

Comment: @Pedro since you say _I can't change the original formula_ my point is not relavent.  (I meant if you could change your `Formula_string` to say `=IFS(N<#>='Z001';'xxxxxx';N<#>='Z007';'xxxxxx';0=0;'xxxxxxx')` then you could replace `<#>` with `i`, but it seems you can't do that)

Comment: @Pedro reliably detecting _all_ and _only_ range references in a formula string is notoriously difficult.  I think the best you can hope for is a method that works for your set of possible formula.  If that list grows, with new patterns, then your method may have to be adapted in future.  With only one example to work from, any reccomendations here (including the answers you've already got) are speculation at best.

Comment: @Pedro, worth noting that `Range.Formula` expects an  American English format formula.  Your example isn't that, the `;` seperators and `'` quotes would fail.  You may have to use `.FormulaLocal` instead

Comment: thank you so much, for the help i will change to FormulaLocal, normally i replace everything to work with formula like ";" for "," and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have written, there are probably better ways to write this code.  But for a regex that will capture just the Column letter in capturing group #1, try:

```
\$?\b(XF[A-D]|X[A-E][A-Z]|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z])\$?(?:104857[0-6]|10485[0-6]\d|1048[0-4]\d{2}|104[0-7]\d{3}|10[0-3]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{1,5}|[1-9])d?
```

Note that is will NOT include the **`$`** absolute addressing token, but could be altered if that were necessary.

Note that you can avoid the loop completely with:

```
    Formula_string = "=IFS(N19=""Z001"",""xxxxxx"",N$19=""Z007"",""xxxxxx"",0=0,""xxxxxxx"")"
    Formula_string_new = regEx.Replace(Formula_string, "$1" & firstRow)

With Range(wb.Cells(firstRow, 33), wb.Cells(lastRow, 33))
    .Clear
    .Formula = Formula_string_new
End With
```

When we write a formula to a range like this, the references will automatically adjust the way you were doing in your loop.

Depending on unstated factors, you may want to use the `FormulaLocal` property vice the `Formula` property.

**Edit:**

To make this a little more robust, in case there happens to be, within the quote marks, a string that exactly mimics a valid address, you can try checking to be certain that a quote (single or double) neither precedes nor follows the target.

```
Pattern:    ([^"'])\$?\b(XF[A-D]|X[A-E][A-Z]|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z])\$?(?:104857[0-6]|10485[0-6]\d|1048[0-4]\d{2}|104[0-7]\d{3}|10[0-3]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{1,5}|[1-9])d?\b(?!['"])

Replace:    "$1$2" & i
```

However, this is not "bulletproof" as various combinations of included data might match. If it is a problem, let me know and I'll come up with something more robust.

Comment: And so the descent into the rabbit hole begins.  Ron, please don't take this as criticism, I'm just saying this task is fraught with difficulty.  As I commented to OP _reliably detecting all and only range references in a formula string is notoriously difficult. I think the best you can hope for is a method that works for your set of possible formula. If that list grows, with new patterns, then your method may have to be adapted in future. With only one example to work from, any recommendations here (including the answers you've already got) are speculation at best._

Comment: @chrisneilsen I absolutely agree. A dedicated parser would be much more useful.

Comment: if vba had negative lookbehind it would be so much easier. My initial test with your solution seen to work. I will test some more to see if is robust enough. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroNadúRangel The problem that conceivably could arise would be if you had, within the quotes, a bounded substring that had the format of a cell address. For example, `=IFS($N2='xyZ1xy';` would be **OK** but `=IFS($N2='xy Z1 xy';` would fail by also matching `Z1`. So it does depend on your data set.  Making your regex object case-sensitive might help to avoid some problems also. And since you are getting the formula from a cell, none of the "real" addresses would be lower case.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify some unique features like in the example preceding bracket ( or colon ; and trailing equal = then this might work

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String, sNew As String, i As Long

    Dim Regex As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Regex
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = False
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .Pattern = "([(;][a-zA-Z]{1,3})(\d+)="
    End With

    i = 1
    s = "=IFS(NANA19='Z001';'xxxxxx';NA19='Z007';'xxxxxx';0=0;'xxxxxxx')"
    sNew = Regex.Replace(s, "$1" & i & "=")

    Debug.Print s & vbCr & sNew

End Sub
```